# I've problems evaluating a symbolic expression

Tags: matlab

I've this error in my code: 
"Undefined function 'integrate'
for input arguments of type
'double'.

Error in
@(t)cos(wc*t+integrate(x1(t),0,t))"

and my code is:

```
f1 = 100;
fc = 5000;
n  = 15; 
w1 = 2*pi*f1;
wc = 2*pi*fc;
fs = 256*fc;
x  = transpose(0:1/fs:n/f1);
lx = length(x);
b  = 0.2;
A1 = b*f1;
x1 = @(t) A1*cos(w1*t);
xc = @(t) cos(wc*t + integrate(x1(t),0,t));
plot(x,xc(x))
```

(i'm trying to modulate x1 with FM)
there is a diffrent way to do this job???

Comment: Where is your symbolic expression? I don't see any smy or smys command.

Comment: This error message can either mean that the function cannot be found or the input arguments are incorrect.  `integrate` is part of the Curve Fitting Toolbox.  I don't have this toolbox, so when I run your code, I receive the same error message.  In the command window, type `which integrate -all` to see if you have this function and `ver` to see if your version of MATLAB includes the Curve Fitting Toolbox.  If not, then you want to use `integral` instead in which case replace `integrate(x1(t),0,t)` with `integral(x1,0,t)`.

Comment: maybe i'm confused but, the expression x1 = @(t) A1*cos(w1*t) works like a symbolic expression, rigth?
@GeoffHayes : I tried to do that but i have now this error:
"Error using integral (line 86)
A and B must be floating point
scalars.

Error in
@(t)cos(wc*t+integral(x1,0,t))"

Comment: The integral of cos being -sin why don't you simply use:
`xc = cos(wc*t - A1/w1*sin(w1*t))` ??

Comment: is just in case that i need another function (and to learn how to do it well).

Comment: @cwichel: No, `x1 = @(t) A1*cos(w1*t)` is not a symbolic expression, it's a function handle and if you use it like you did (input argument vector) it does not use the symbolic toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the symbolic toolbox, define functions of type symfun:

```
syms t
x1(t)=A1*cos(w1*t);
```

now you can easily integrate:

```
Ix1=int(x1)
xc(t)=cos(wc*t + Ix1(t)-Ix1(0))
```

Comment: Using symfun is not the OP's issue. The issue is the use of `integrate` (a barely documented function in the curve fitting toolbox) instead of `sym/int`. And not defining `t` as symbolic. The `int` function works perfectly fine with generic symbolic variables and anonymous functions.